# Getting rid of orphan role permissions

Tags: upgrading, 10

In the course of trying to uprade from D9.5 to D10 I face the following annoying problem:
When I uninstalled the guestbook modules some time ago under D8 or D9, it didn't remove its permissions. D10 won't accept this. The module cannot be re-installed either at my Drupal level. Neither can I use drush cex or the UI, because both crash.
The directory and module for guestbook don't exist anymore.

Is there a way to get rid of the permissions within the MySQL database?

Comment: "TypeError: array_flip(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, string given in /home/hs/www10/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/ExcludedModulesEventSubscriber.php on line 136" is caused by a copy of example.settings.local.php where you have a string instead of an array: `$settings['config_exclude_modules'] = ['devel', 'stage_file_proxy'];` )

Answer (score 1):

If you are using config sync, you can edit the yml files for your permissions (one file per role) and remove the offending permissions. Then perform a config import.

Edit: Just saw that you can't use drush cex, you are going to need that, so best to work that out before trying to move forward on this issue. If you are already on 10, you are going to have to roll back to 9, remove the permissions and then upgrade again. D10 will throw a fatal error for orphaned permissions so no way around that. I assume you made backups?

You can use a module like upgrade status to track your readiness level.

Comment: If you don't want to restore a backup you could hack the D10 core and remove the code line throwing the fatal error. Of course only temporarily to run drush cex/cim. Check the error logs to locate the code.